# How to use Read command in echo like fill in the blanks

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Am writing a script.Eg:

```
echo "my name is 'read' and am from 'read' city" > outfile.txt
```

When it runs it's not printing the sentence first, i.e `my name is`.              Rather it's asking first to enter 2 inputs for 2 read commands used, then its forming the complete sentence like "my name is **sudhir** and am from **vizag** city"

I want script to execute 1st "my name is `read(ask for input)` and am from `read(ask for another input)` city" and after giving inputs it should redirect to outfile.txt      in one shot.

How to handle this? Is it feasible to achieve in single sentence?

Because I want to use same logic for 480 questions all in one file and persons how don't have any scripting knowledge should able to add more questions taking reference of previous questions present in same file.

Comment: no man function I tried that work same as example I provided above, it will promote 1st to give value for read command used and then it will print full line. here end user wont come to know what he is entering, as here its not asking like fill in the blank format. for every question I cannot create separate echo command asking enter 1st value enter 2nd value etc. I want a universal solution to apply for all 480 questions, Please share example if u have solution with function, it will be very helpful !!

Comment: As 1 question may require 3 read commands another question 5 read commands. Please share example if u have solution with function

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a pretty way to do this, since `read` writes the newline character from the input to the terminal, but we can do this in two passes.

1. Get the input from the user
2. Write the results to the file

You could put the following in a script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n 'my name is '; read -r name
echo -n ' and I am from '; read -r city
echo ' city'

printf "my name is %s and I am from %s city\n" \
   "$name" "$city" > output.txt
```

And to the user it would look like this

```
my name is sudhir
and I am from vizag
city
```

But it would be like this in the file

```
my name is sudhir and I am from vizag city
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that takes a string with placeholders and asks the user to input for each of them:

```
#!/bin/bash

fill() {
  arg="$*"
  result=""
  while [[ "$arg" =~ ([^_]*)(_+)(.*) ]]
  do
    read -rp "${BASH_REMATCH[1]# }${BASH_REMATCH[2]}: " input
    result+="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${input}"
    arg="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
  done
  result+="$arg"
  printf '%s\n' "$result"
}

exec > outputfile
fill "My name is ____ and I am from ___."
fill "My new years resolution is ____."
```

Example:

```
$ ./myscript
My name is ____: Sudhir
and I am from ___: Vizag
My new years resolution is ____: learning Bash instead of asking SO to write my scripts

$ cat outputfile
My name is Sudhir and I am from Vizag.
My new years resolution is learning Bash instead of asking SO to write my scripts.
```